# kendo core AutoComplete dropdown show only undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, autocomplete

I created a simple ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app. I want to create an AutoComplete with kendo core.

All do like written https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/getting-started/first-steps and still if try send to AutoComplete from controller dropdown show undefined.

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
        .Name("market")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .Filter("contains")
        .DataSource(source =>
            source.Read(read =>
                read.Action("GetItems", "Home")
            )
            .ServerFiltering(true)
        )
        )
</div>
```

HomeController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;
using TestDELETE_ME.Models;

namespace TestDELETE_ME.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public JsonResult GetItems()
        {
            List<CauViewModel> products = new List<CauViewModel>();
            products.Add(new CauViewModel { Id = 1, Name = "cat" });
            products.Add(new CauViewModel { Id = 2, Name = "dog" });
            products.Add(new CauViewModel { Id = 3, Name = "bird" });
            return Json(products);
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace TestDELETE_ME.Models
{
    public class CauViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[AutoComplete example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4gQH.png)

Show correct in dropdown

Comment: Here is a [Docs](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/index) about how to achieve AutoComplete in dendo, you can refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `undefined` indicates the AutoComplete is receiving data, but it is not in the expected format. If you inspect the request and it is in camelCase, rather than PascalCase, set the [JSON serialization](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/installation/json-serialization).

Comment: Best answer. Tnx! Think for beginners it will be true saver!

Comment: I'm running into the same issue, @PavelsFilipovs. I have the JsonSerializerOptions set to CamelCase, but I'm still seeing undefined only. Can you advise how you did it?

Comment: Either configure the JSON serialization to use PascalCase `.AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);` or set the DataTextField configuration to the camelCased property - `.DataTextField("name")`.